# Xsl-fo resize fo:block to textwidth

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

is it possible to fit the width of a fo:block element to the width of the text in the element? I've tried width auto, but that doesn't worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand the question (and after five years, you might not either).  If you want a property, such as `background-color`, to apply to just a run of text, you can use `fo:inline` or `fo:inline-container`:

```
<fo:block space-after="1em">
    <fo:inline-container>
        <fo:block background-color="yellow">I am the very model</fo:block>
    </fo:inline-container>
</fo:block>
<fo:block space-after="1em">
    <fo:inline background-color="yellow">I am the very model</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "width" property doesn't apply to fo:block. Have a look this post to expore and resolve your query [FOP: fo:block width attribute ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888997/fop-foblock-width-attribute-ignored)